# problem with my insert sort code. cant change index 0 element in array

Tags: java, sorting, insert

I have a task to write an Insert Sort method and Im pretty sure Im on the right way. Somehow, if I let the test play I get that error

```
"org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Results: [3, 8, 1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0] Expected: [1, 3, 8, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0] ==> array contents differ at index [0], expected: <3> but was: <1>"
```

I understand, that I need to swap at `index [0]`, but I believe my code is able to do that.

```
public static<T> void insertSort(T[]data, Comparator<T>compar, Consumer<T[]> output) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            T jetzt = data[i];
            int j = i-1;

            while(j >= 0 && compar.compare(data[j], data[i]) > 0) {
                data[j+1] = data[j];
                j--;
            }

            data[j+1] = jetzt;



            output.accept(data);
        }
    }
```

Either Im missing something or Im on the wrong way.

Tried to fix the index 0 problem.

Comment: Try to use a debugger to find out what is happening here

Comment: Im not sure If I used the debugger right, but If I debug the testInsertSort, I get this =SimpleSortingTest@1883 ; results = null

Comment: You should debug `insertSort`. BTW: implement `toString()` in `SimpleSortingTest` will show you the details